# React Native - How to optimize the rendering of FlatList's item, or doing non-shallow comparison on extraData?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am working hard on optimizing my `<FlatList />` component, here are my sample codes:

---

#### Case 1:

https://snack.expo.io/HrpJli9EE

I am trying to increase the number of id in `selectedIds`.
However as the `selectedIds` in context doesn't change reference,
and `<FlatList />` is doing a shallow comparison,
so the items didn't re-rendered with the value in context.

---

#### Case 2:

https://snack.expo.io/wRLNRYAmU

Therefore I try to make a new object reference every time when the item is pressed,
(Only change line 17 from Case 1's link)
The items can now re-rendered with the new values.
**However**, the `memo()` is not working for the `<Item />` component,
which may lead to heavy loading for a large list.

---

#### So...

**Case 1:** Is there any way to let `<FlatList />` not doing shallow comparison with `extraData`?

#### Or...

**Case 2:** Is there any way to prevent re-render in the `<Item />` component if item value is the same?

i.e. If I press the first item to increase number,
as the second item and third item's number are not increasing, **they should not re-render**
but currently, they do re-rendered.

Appreciate any answers or comments.

---

**Reminder:** You can open the console panel by pressing "Editor" in bottom bar > enable "Panel" > press "LOG".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out using **case 2** with `useMemo` instead of `memo` can reduce unnecessary rendering of unchanged item:

```js
import React, { useContext, useMemo } from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import { styles } from './styles';

const Item = ({ item, onPress }) => {
  const { selectedIds } = useContext(AppContext);
  const value = selectedIds[item.id] || 0;
  const onItemPress = () => onPress(item.id, value + 1);

  return useMemo(() => {
    /* You will only see this console log when this item value is updated */
    console.log("render item", item.id, value);
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={onItemPress} style={styles.item}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title} {value}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }, [value]);
};
```